# Javascript dispatch events

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

I'm using a Javascript plugin and this dispatch a click event over a select. My problem is when I try to catch this event with jQuery delegated event doesn't work. With normal jQuery listener work's fine.

Is there a way to catch dispatch Javascript events with jQuery delegated events?

Comment: Show what you tried that does not work

Answer (score 0):

You need to make it *bubble*, by setting your [Event's *eventInit* `bubbles`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event) property to true.

But note that if you don't need a native DOM-Event, you could also just use [jQuery's `.trigger()`](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/) method which does bubble.

```js
$('#parent').on('my-event', '#target', (evt) =>
  console.log( evt.type, 'fired' )
);

console.log('non bubbling');
const nonBubbling = new Event('my-event');
$('#target')[0].dispatchEvent( nonBubbling );

console.log('bubbling');
const bubbling = new Event('my-event', { bubbles: true } );
$('#target')[0].dispatchEvent( bubbling );

console.log('$.trigger');
$('#target').trigger('my-event')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <span id="target"></span>
</div>
```